# Do questions on software's "terms of use" belong on SU?

Tags: discussion, policy, legality

Do questions on software's "terms of use" (what you need to click agree and accept... to install software), belong on SU?

Comment: No, they don't.

Comment: @Sathya: Thanks, would you prefer I delete the question?

Comment: I'd let it remain - someone will probably write a nice answer :) dropped a comment since I'm bit preoccupied to write an answer

Comment: OK... I just don't want any downvotes (I'm so close to 2,000 REP)

Comment: just FYI your meta.SU rep is derived from SU - in other words, voting in this meta has got no effect on your rep :)

Comment: I don't understand why this question deserved a downvote anyway. There's nothing to disagree with (he didn't even say, "I think they should be on topic".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Super User is for questions regarding computer hardware and software. A Terms of Service is a legal thing, and almost never has any impact on usage of the software itself. Unless of course, somehow hitting NO will install the program anyway, then limit features, or something along those lines. But that never happens.

I don't believe there is any valid Stack Exchange site for such a question currently. As always though, feel free to drop by the Chat and have a talk about it!

Comment: Software law is also very hard to analyze since it's different in every country, and ostensibly unenforceable in all of them. Makes it very hard to write a constructive question about it.

Comment: Thank you very much Simon.  Should I bring the question to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @wizlog take a look at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3527/software-law

Comment: @SimonSheehan Thanks.